# протокол p2p в программах

Tags: c++, c, бот, p2p

Для чего в ботнетах используется p2p? Какой принцип работы p2p ботнета? Вчера прочитала новость о ботнете таком. Вопрос обычно p2p используется в torrent для скачивания. Зачем они его используют? Фильмы скачивать что-ли.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score -1):

Если очень сильно вкратце, то в централизованной сети, боты подключатся к одному или нескольким серверам для приема команд.

Если есть например один главный сервер, и он отпадет, то все боты потеряют связь с ним.

Ниже изображена схема работы централизованных ботнетов.

[image: Схема работы централизованных ботнетов]

В бот-сети P2P, не существует централизованного сервера. Каждый бот может действовать как C&C сервер, так и клиент.

Ниже изображена схема работы P2P ботнетов

[image: Схема работы P2P ботнетов]

Информация, в том числе и картинки, были взяты с этого сайта: [ссылка](https://www.anti-malware.ru/analytics/Threats_Analysis/An-Overview-of-Peer-to-peer-Botnets)